# Print dynamically in just one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

Been trying to improve my Fibonacci script. Made a few changes regarding actually how it visually looks (has like a minimalist "menu") and some other stuff to avoid it breaking, like not allowing text to be given as input to the amount of numbers it should generate. One of the things I wanted to change was the output to show all in just one line, but kinda been having a hard time doing so.

My code:

```
count = int(input("How many numbers do you want to generate?"))

a = 0
b = 0
c = 1
i = 0

while i < count:
    print(str(c))
    a = b
    b = c
    c = a + b
    i = i+1
```

What I also tried:
Instead of
`print(str(c))` I've tried, without any luck:

```
    print("\033[K", str(c), "\r", )
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Desired output:

```
1, 1, 2, 3 ,5
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
3
5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `end` parameter of the `print` function, specifically in your example:

```
while i < count:
    print(c, end=", ")
    ...
```

To prevent the trailing comma after the last print:

```
while i < count:
    print(c, end=("" if i == count - 1 else ", "))
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, was actually forgetting I could specify how it'd end with the `end` parameter. Just want to point out that you can't really use `print(str(c, end=", "))` but instead must use `print(c, end=", ")` since `end` is an invalid keyword argument for str(). It did work out after fixing that, thanks a lot

Comment: You're right, mistake with the parantheses 
Fixed now

Comment: Btw, casting to `int`s to `str` is not necessary for the print function as it does it automatically

Answer (score 2):

You can specifiy the ending of `print`:

```
print(*[1,2,3], end=", ")
```

The default ending is a new line

You can also specifiy a different separator with `sep=", "`

Comment: This will still result in a newline ending. Did you mean to use `end` instead of `sep`?

Comment: This won't work, the question is asking how to print the values as they are generated, this answer requires that the values be stored in a list before being printed. You should explicitly state that.

Comment: Yes, my test was wrong. In his case he's printing in a while loop, so there must be `end`